# An internal error occurred during: "Building"

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

After adding a plugin to my pom.xml I am getting this error.

> An internal error occurred during: "Building".
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Try to update the question to highlight your problem with the complete pom.xml and any other concerned file. We can't help as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are building the application using JDK version 9 or above. It is supported till JDK 8.

Comment: What is "it" in "It is supported till JDK 8"?

Comment: most of reflection packages are removed in the latest JDK

Comment: I get this error with JDK8, minor version 181

Answer (score 0):

My issue was different and below maven plugin was causing the problem.

> jaxb2-maven-plugin

It may be your xsd or wsdl issue, if maven is not able to compile it properly.

Comment: which JDK version you are using to build the application?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on project --> Run as --> Maven generate sources

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the later version, but if you are using the 1.6 version of xjc just change the JRE (whatever) to JavaSE-1.8. To change the JRE in eclipse, Right click on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Select JRE System Library and click on edit button and then select the Execution Environment. Hope it works for you !!